# Convert Parameter Query to Take Parameter from Table

Tags: sql, parameters, subquery

I been unable to figure out a way to do the query below without using a parameter.  The database has over 2000 possible values for the parameter, so what I want is to output a table that lists all the parameters in one column, and the output from the query in the other.  Below is a simplified version of what works now:

```
SELECT [enter name] AS ExclName, 
       Sum(revenue) AS MaxRev 
FROM   tbltasks 
WHERE  tbltasks.task IN (SELECT DISTINCT tblabilities.task 
                         FROM   tblabilities 
                         WHERE  tblabilities.name <> [enter name]); 

    tbltasks                tblpeople       tblabilities            
    task    revenue         name            name    task                
    A       10              Bob             Bob     A    
    B       9               Tom             Tom     A    
    C       8               Jack            Jack    A    
    D       7               Mary            Tom     B    
    E       6               Diane           Jack    B    
    F       5               Alice           Mary    B    
    G       4               Sam             Jack    C    
    H       3                               Mary    C    
    I       2                               Diane   C    
                                            Mary    D    
                                            Diane   D    
                                            Alice   D    
                                            Diane   E    
                                            Alice   E    
                                            Sam     E    
                                            Bob     F    
                                            Tom     G    
                                            Alice   H
```

Right now I run the query, manually enter a name like "Bob" when prompted, and get a single row of output like:

```
ExclName   MaxRev
Bob         47
```

But what I want is the complete table:

```
ExclName   MaxRev
Bob         47
Tom         48
Jack        52
Mary        52
Diane       52
Alice       49
Sam         52
```

Or in other words, I want to know what maximum revenue could be achieved by a team that excluded the named member.  The real application is more complicated, as there are other groupings involved (eg. if exclude Jack, must also exclude Mary), but I think if I solve the simple problem above I can handle the rest.

I keep thinking there must be a way to use the names from tblPeople and link them to the MaxRev calculation with a single query, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  I could do some code to loop through all the parameters, but am hoping there is a more straightforward solution.  Appreciate anyone's input.

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply extend your query for all people:

```
select
   p.name as ExclName, 
   sum(t.revenue) as MaxRev 
from tblpeople as p
    cross join tbltasks as t
where
    t.task in
    (
       select l.task 
       from tblabilities as l
       where l.name <> p.name
    )
group by p.name
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d393/3)

**update**. Still don't know which RDBMS do you using, here's SQL Server solution, it's possible to split solution below into temp table, variable and query to improve performance, but it should be faster than first one anyway (if you have appropriate indexes on your table):

```
with cte as (
    select l.[name], sum(t.[revenue]) as [revenue]
    from tblabilities as l
        inner join tbltasks as t on t.[task] = l.[task]
    where
        not exists
        (
            select * 
            from tblabilities as tl
            where tl.[task] = l.[task] and tl.[name] <> l.[name]
        )
    group by l.[name]
)
select
    p.[name] as ExclName,
    t.revenue_total - isnull(c.[revenue], 0) as MaxRev
from tblpeople as p
    left outer join cte as c on c.[name] = p.[name]
    outer apply (
        select sum(tt.[revenue]) as revenue_total
        from tbltasks as tt
        where
            tt.[task] in (select tl.[task] from tblabilities as tl)
    ) as t
order by p.[name]
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d393/13)

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround.  It works.  I dont' think I've ever used a cross join before, and am a little concerned about how that is going to scale up.  The real problem has 1.8 million rows in the table equivalent to "tbltasks" and 2200 rows in the one equivalent to tblpeople, so that cross is going to be huge.  Not sure what is going to happen when I try.  Might be a couple of days before I get a chance to test, but will post back when I do.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I submitted the query on the full database yesterday and after 24 hours it still hasn't completed.  So I think the cross join is just too big.  Any other suggestions, or is this a case where a parameter query is the best solution?  Thanks.

Comment: do you have any indexes on your tables? I'll check how query could be changed, by suggestion was just extension of your query

Comment: Yes, I have indexes on every field that is involved in a join or a where clause.

Comment: @BunkerBob see updated and please tell me do you using SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL?

Comment: Thanks again for your help Roman.  I'm tied up for the next day or so but will try out your suggestion as soon as I can... looks very promising.  The database was given to me in MS Access... will probably be moving it to MySQL but right now need to get this to work in Access which is a pain because among other things I'm hitting a 2 GB file size limit which inexplicably still applies to 64bit Access on 64bit Windows.  Don't worry about trying to post Access SQL... I can do the translation. Will post back as soon as I get a chance. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Roman... thanks again for your help.  I did manage to get your code working on my test data and I _think_ it can work on the real data as well but have gotten bogged down with extending the logic to cover some other constraints, so thought I should post back rather than leave you hanging.  I think we can consider the issue closed, because between your first and second posts I'm pretty sure you've given me enough insight to wrestle this to the ground.  Thanks again.